# How can I quickly see if an OS X Kext is leaking memory?

Tags: macos, memory-leaks

I recently saw that kernel indicated that something, somewhere, had a memory leak -- `kernel_task` had paged out over 10 GiB of ram. Due to  fact that I've added a variety of different third-party kexts, I'd like to quickly know if any of them are leaking, before I look around elsewhere to track down the leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice simple one-liner to show if there are any `kext` leaks: if the ranges of memory currently allocated ('wired') are different to those that the kernel expected it allocated, then a process is leaking. Just by running

```
diff <(kextstat|tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 5) <(kextstat| tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6)
```

we can immediately see if anything is misbehaving. The only difference between the two fields should be their names; if there is a mismatch, something is leaking.